# reusable app (package) in Django - how to add extra models

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

I am writing a small package that extends the django app that is used by many of my colleagues locally. So right now they can simply add it via pip, and then they add this extension in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

But the problem is that I can't add the new models to this extension (or at least I don't figure out yet how to do it correctly) because then  the guys who would like to use my extension, have to sync their database or make migrations so their database contains the models needed for extension.

Is it possible (and right thing to do) to add new models to the current django project 'silently' as soon as the user adds the app to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: add the models and corresponding migration files in the package itself.

Comment: hi! yes, I added the models. But what do you mean by 'corresponding migration files'?